# Passing two json parameters with curl

Tags: json, rest, curl, request

Right now, i am using curl in order to pass a parameter to a server's endpoint.

Here is my request:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data '{"item":"myItem1.txt"}' 0.0.0.0:5000/parse
```

As, you can see, i am only passing one parameter, which is the `myItem1`.
Now, i am in a situation, where i want to pass two parameters.
Two different items, let's say.

How do i do that, using curl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a second property:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data '{"item":"myItem1.txt", "otherItem": "myItem2.txt"}' 0.0.0.0:5000/parse
```

or an array of items either as

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data '[{"item":"myItem1.txt"}, {"item":"myItem2.txt"}]' 0.0.0.0:5000/parse
```

or as

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data '{"item":["myItem1.txt", "myItem2.txt"]}' 0.0.0.0:5000/parse
```